# Getting an exception related to Elmah after removing it from project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I suppose I forgot something silly while removing Elmah because I'm getting a binding exception at run time...

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Elmah' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

A global solution search for the word Elmah (case insensitive) revealed nothing. I have cleaned the solution, emptied the bin folder, checked into IIS express settings. Not a single word about Elmah... I don't know where else to look.

### Assembly Load Trace

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Elmah
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Elmah | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///W:/ImplementationSuiviProjet/Source/Portail/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = W:\ImplementationSuiviProjet\Source\Portail\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: W:\ImplementationSuiviProjet\Source\Portail\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Pier-Luc Michaud\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/portail/9481be8a/4a40a731/Elmah.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/portail/9481be8a/4a40a731/Elmah/Elmah.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///W:/ImplementationSuiviProjet/Source/Portail/bin/Elmah.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///W:/ImplementationSuiviProjet/Source/Portail/bin/Elmah/Elmah.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/portail/9481be8a/4a40a731/Elmah.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/portail/9481be8a/4a40a731/Elmah/Elmah.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///W:/ImplementationSuiviProjet/Source/Portail/bin/Elmah.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///W:/ImplementationSuiviProjet/Source/Portail/bin/Elmah/Elmah.EXE.
```

### Stack Trace

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Elmah' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +37
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +65
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Elmah' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +353
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit) +21
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +39
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +42
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +160
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1068
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +82
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Elmah' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10037820
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

[Web.config](http://pastebin.ca/2998980)

[.csproj](http://pastebin.ca/2998978)

Comment: Have you checked through your config file?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant by global solution search. It included config files.

Comment: Where was it configured prior to removal - was it all in your web.config?

Comment: try deleting your asp.net temp files

Comment: Can you show your .csproject and web.config?

Comment: @PrakashKalakoti How?

Comment: @Kamo Added pastebin links

Answer (score 0):

Seems IIS configs were corrupted. I deleted the site and it works fine now. I'm really confused how the file got corrupted however. It was fine when I left the office yesterday.

It has to do with working between different branches of the same project but I can't really say exactly what caused it.